# Get the Start and End of the Day in timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

How can I get the start and end of the day in timestamp?

Output like:

```
04/01/2014 00:00:00

04/01/2014 23:59:59
```

Comment: you can't, timestamp as the name suggests, is one particular instance of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There probably is a better way to do it but I think this should work.

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'), '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') as morning,
  DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59'), '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') as evening
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/34947)