# Is this the proper way to get the end of day in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time, format

I'm getting the End Of Day like this:

```
function endofday($date_to_change)
{
  $date_to_change = date('Y-m-d');
  $date_to_change = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+23 hours 59 minutes  59 seconds", strtotime($date_to_change)));
  return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date_to_change);
}
```

It works but is this the proper and most efficient way to get 23:59:59 from a date? My goal is to select rows from a mysql database between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 from a date passed in with or without time.

Comment: Use MYSQL for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874431/get-the-start-and-end-of-the-day-in-timestamp-in-mysql

Comment: Hi Chris I'm looking for the correct PHP function, then pass in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и так
 
$begin = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
$end = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime($date_to_change));

Comment: This will not work, if `$begin` is calclated before and `$end` after a day change. You have to use `$begin` as reference time, for example: `$end = $begin + 86399`. But this solution have another issue, on days with daylight saving changes.

Comment: @Wimm for daylight saving then would you suggest getting midnight from next day then subtract 1 second (or millisecond) ?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use this kind of SQL query

```
where end_date < '2020-09-01' # this date is 1 day after the actual end date
```

You can use [DateTime()](https://www.php.net/datetime) function

```php
$endDate = date_create('2020-08-31')->modify('+1 day -1 microsecond')

// or, similar result
$endDate = new DateTime('2020-08-31');
$endDate->modify('+1 day -1 microsecond');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `date >= start && date < end`?

In general, working with inclusive beginning and exclusive end is a standard programming way. Otherwise you will exclude 23:59:59.500.

Also you get always correct (time) differences if using `end-start`.

Finally you can use `end` as start for the next range without adjusting it.

In my opinion, using an exclusive end value/time has only advantages.

I you want to print the time, you can use `time-1` to print `23:59:59`, or `time-0.001` to print `23:59:59.999`. Anyway people understand the meaning of `until 20:00` as times before `20:00`.

Comment: Yes you are correct for the query part of this... which typically would mean the php function I was looking for not needed, but I'm working with existing code and I need a function to adjust variables.

Answer (score 1):

This could potentially be another solution.

```
$today = new \DateTime('midnight today');
$endOfDay = (new \DateTime('midnight tomorrow'));
var_dump($today < $endOfDay);

var_dump($today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // 2022-02-08 00:00:00
var_dump($endOfDay->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // 2022-02-09 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

More readable way to get end of given day nowdays would be

```php
function endOfDay(string $dateToChange): \DateTime
{
    return (new \DateTime($dateToChange))->setTime(23, 59, 59);
}

var_dump(endOfDay('2019-05-04'));
```

will give you (*take note that `\DateTime` contains TZ info*)

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-05-04 23:59:59.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
  ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC"
}
```

**But**, as @*Wiimm* mentioned in his answer, this way you'll be missing a second out of day. So it would be more correct to use

```php
function startOfDay(\DateTime $dt): \DateTime
{
    return (clone $dt)->setTime(0, 0, 0);
}
```

and correct comparison:

```php
$date = new \DateTime('2019-05-04 15:25:13'); // 2019-05-04 15:25:13.000000
$dateNextDay = (clone $date)->modify('+1 day'); // 2019-05-05 15:25:13.000000

$isInBetween = startOfDay($date) <= $date && $date < startOfDay($dateNextDay); // true
```

*Take note of using `clone`(*otherwise original `$date` would be modified*) and completely switching to `DateTime`.*

Most of ORMs already knows how to work with `\DateTime`, but if you need to convert it to string:

```php
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2019-05-04 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the start and end of day by setting the proper time part.

Given a date-time object:

```
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2024-03-01');
```

- Date at start of the day:

```
    $startOfTheDay = $date->setTime(0,0);
```

- Date at end of the day:

```
    $endOfTheDay = date->setTime(23,59,59,999999);
```